# cannot display markers in google map v3 from DB via TWIG

Tags: symfony, google-maps-api-3, twig

Hi everyone im trying to  display multiple markers in a google map  , the location of thise markers is based on latitude and longitude from my database  but when i execute the code  the map is displayed but the not the markers.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', function(){


    var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(36.8064948,10.181531599999971),
zoom:8,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
 ,mapProp);   


    {% for pharmacies in pharmacie %} 

 var coordinates= new         





google.maps.LatLng(phamacies.latitude|json_encode(),pharmacies.longitude|json_encode()
);

var marker= new google.maps.Marker({position:coordinates,title:"Pharmacie"});

  marker.setMap(map);  


{% endfor %}  





});


 the controller:

    public function latlongAction()
    {

   $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
   $pharmacies=$em->getRepository('PharmacieBundle:Pharmacie')->findAll();
    return $this->container->get('templating')-   
    >renderResponse('TemplateBundle:Default:layout.html.twig', array(
        'pharmacie' => $pharmacies
        ));      



    }

 thanks.
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a similar issue.
It seems that the problem comes form your {% for pharmacies in pharmacie %} line.
You can't use the twig syntax inside of your script. So you have to work around it.

One way to do it would be getting your data from an HTML element with data-lat and data-lng attributes. Probably not the best work around but it works.